# Facebook - How to create an URL to fanpage from fanpage name?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a fanpage name, for example: "Funny Vines". Real URL of this fanpage is: https://www.facebook.com/funnyvinesofficalpage/

How I can get/create this URL when I have only name of this fanpage ("Funny Vines")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Search API:

```
/search?type=page&q=Funny Vines&fields=name,link
```

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

Keep in mind that this is a search, so you don´t just get one result, obviously:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Funny Vines",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/funnyvinesofficalpage/",
      "id": "662605137102011"
    },
    {
      "name": "Funny Vines",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/FunnyVinesLovers/",
      "id": "979586622060309"
    },
    {
      "name": "Iligan Funny Vines and Pictures",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Iligan-Funny-Vines-and-Pictures-304142043018984/",
      "id": "304142043018984"
    },
    {
      "name": "Funny Vines",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/vines6/",
      "id": "433033710153363"
    },
    {
      "name": "Funny Viral Vines",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Funny-Viral-Vines-1375072712767279/",
      "id": "1375072712767279"
    },
    ...
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 17 seconds - and with a more detailed answer, too! =)

Comment: lucky luke of stackoverflow :)